# Microsoft SQL Server SELECT statement

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, select

I need help retrieving `ReceiptNO` column from a database table and saving it into a `TextBox` or `Label` for referencing.

CODE:

```vb
Dim da2 As New SqlDataAdapter
da2.SelectCommand = New SqlCommand("SELECT RecepitNO FROM Receipt WHERE (PaidFor=@PaidFor AND RegNO=@RegNO)")
da2.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@paidFor", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = cbMonth.Text
da2.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@RegNO", SqlDbType.Int).Value = lblRegNO.Text

cn.Open()
da2.Update(ds.Tables("Receipt"))
'da2.SelectCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
da2.SelectCommand.ExecuteReader()
cn.Close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a [SqlDataReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.aspx), and then start a loop to read the values returned
This example will work assuming the ReceiptNO is a text field

```
cn.Open()
Dim reader = da2.SelectCommand.ExecuteReader()
while reader.Read()
    textBox1.Text = reader("ReceiptNO").ToString()
End While
```

In alternative, if you are sure that your query returns zero or just one record and you are interested only in the ReceiptNO field, then you can use ExecuteScalar

```
Dim cmd = New SqlCommand("SELECT RecepitNO FROM Receipt WHERE (PaidFor=@PaidFor AND RegNO=@RegNO)")
cmd.Connection = cn
cmd.Parameters.Add("@paidFor", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = cbMonth.Text
cmd.Parameters.Add("@RegNO", SqlDbType.Int).Value = lblRegNO.Text
cn.Open()
Dim result = cmd.ExecuteScalar()
if result IsNot Nothing Then
    textBox1.Text = result.ToString()
End If
```

[Here the MSDN docs on ExecuteScalar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx)

Comment: my fields only return 1 receiptNO... thanks.. shall try the btm method

Comment: Revised the second example to add the connection object

Comment: it gives me InvalidOperationException was unhandled for DIM result = cmd.executeScalar

Comment: ReceiptNO is Int (datatype) in my database... does this method still works?

Comment: Yes, it should work, at least this is not a problem for the ExecuteScalar

Comment: Which is the datatype for the fields used for the Where clause ?

Comment: i dont get your question but i think WHERE is a condition for the select statement?

Comment: Did you open the connection? http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311544/en-us also do you have an inner exception? Check the Details link on the Exception Message (of course when debugging in Visual Studio IDE)